# Chaining animations and memory management

Tags: iphone, memory-management, animation

Got a question.  I have a subclassed UIView that is acting as my background where I am scrolling the ground.  The code is working really nice and according to the Instrumentation, I am not leaking nor is my created and still living Object allocation growing.

I have discovered else where in my application that adding an animation to a UIImageView that is owned by my subclassed UIView seems to bump up my retain count and removing all animations when I am done drops it back down.

My question is this, when you add an animation to a layer with a key, I am assuming that if there is already a used animation in that entry position in the backing dictionary that it is released and goes into the autorelease pool?

For example:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSString *keyValue = [theAnimation valueForKey:@"name"];
    if ( [keyValue isEqual:@"step1"] && flag ) {
        groundImageView2.layer.position = endPos;

        CABasicAnimation *position = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        position.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
        position.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:midEndPos];
        position.duration = (kGroundSpeed/3.8);
        position.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        [position setDelegate:self];
        [position setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
        [position setValue:@"step2-1" forKey:@"name"];

        [groundImageView2.layer addAnimation:position forKey:@"positionAnimation"]; 

        groundImageView1.layer.position = startPos;
        position = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        position.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
        position.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:midStartPos];
        position.duration = (kGroundSpeed/3.8);
        position.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        [position setDelegate:self];
        [position setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
        [position setValue:@"step2-2" forKey:@"name"];

        [groundImageView1.layer addAnimation:position forKey:@"positionAnimation"]; 
    }
    else if ( [keyValue isEqual:@"step2-2"] && flag ) {
        groundImageView1.layer.position = midStartPos;

        CABasicAnimation *position = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        position.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
        position.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPos];
        position.duration = 12;
        position.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        [position setDelegate:self];
        [position setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
        [position setValue:@"step1" forKey:@"name"];

        [groundImageView1.layer addAnimation:position forKey:@"positionAnimation"]; 
    }
}
```

This chains animations infinitely, and as I said one it is running the created and living object allocation doesn't change.  I am assuming everytime I add an animation the one that exists in that key position is released.

Just wondering I am correct.  Also, I am relatively new to Core Animation.  I tried to play around with re-using the animations but got a little impatient.  Is it possible to reuse animations?

Thanks!
Bryan

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is difficult to verify without Apple's source code. When you call `addAnimation:forKey:`, the `CALayer` makes a copy of the animation object. There is no guarantee from the API (in the docs or elsewhere) that it will release a running animation when another is added for the same key. It would be much safer for you to explicitly call `removeAnimation:forKey:` rather than relying on the API to do what you want.

Also, why have you set `removedOnCompletion` to `NO` in the code above? The default behavior of a `CAAnimation` is to remove itself from the layer once it has completed, and then call `animationDidStop:finished:` on the delegate. You can then add any other animation to the layer with the same key. Isn't this exactly what you're trying to do? It seems like you might be over thinking it a little.

As for your question about reusing animations: since the animation object is copied when added to a `CALayer`, you can hold a reference to an animation object that you create and keep adding it to as many layers as you want as many times as you like.

Comment: With regards to `removedOnCompletion`, other answers on stackoverflow indicate that unless you have this set to `NO` and `fillMode` to `kCAFillModeForwards`, the results of your animation will not be persistent. That is, any property changes will be removed with the removal of the `CAAnimation` from the `CALayer`. Apple obviously wanted animation of properties to be non-destructive. You can set the properties to a final state using the `animationDidStop:finished` method, but you will often end up with a graphical "blip" where the CALayer reverts to its pre-animated state. It looks dreadful.

Comment: That is mostly correct, but there is a simpler way. The animation is not applied to the layer itself. Rather a copy, called the `presentationLayer`, is created, and the animation is applied to it. Also, since every iteration of the main runloop is wrapped in an implicit `CATransaction`, you can set the final properties of your layer before you add the animation. All of the changes, including the animation, will be submitted at once, and there will be no blip at the beginning or end. For example: `myLayer.position = CGPointMake(100, 100); [myLayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position"];`